# "Twig_Error_Loader Unable to find template", due to slashes added to template name

Tags: php, macos, apache, twig

After upgrading macOS server, Twig seems to have broken. For some reason, the function normalizeName($name) in lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php is breaking, and returning the template name with a slash before every character. For example, "index.html" becomes "/i/n/d/e/x/./h/t/m/l".

So when I try and use Twig's render() function that calls normalizeName(), I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader' with message 'Unable to find template "/l/o/g/i/n/./h/t/m/l/" (looked into: /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/templates).'

Modifying normalizeName() so it simply returns what it was passed results in PHP terminating the script due to memory exhaustion (at about 125MB) in lib/Twig/Lexer.php on line 107.

The code with the problem is below.

```
require_once '/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Twig/lib/Twig/autoloader.php';

Twig_Autoloader::register();

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/templates/');

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => '/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/cache/',
    'auto_reload' => 1
));

$twig -> render('login.html');
```

The full stack trace:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader' with message 'Unable to find template "/l/o/g/i/n/./h/t/m/l/" (looked into: /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/sccs_templates).' in /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php:247
>
> Stack trace: 
>   #0/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php(159): Twig_Loader_Filesystem->findTemplate('login.html')
>
> #1 /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(329): Twig_Loader_Filesystem->getCacheKey('login.html')
>
> #2 /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(418): Twig_Environment->getTemplateClass('login.html', NULL)
>
> #3 /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(362): Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('login.html')
>
> #4 /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/sccs_includes/setup.php(252): Twig_Environment->render('login.html', Array)
>
> #5 /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/sccs/index.php(3): require_once('/Library/Server...')
>
> #6 {main} thrown in /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php on line 247

I'm running Yosemite with Apache 2.4.23 and PHP 5.5.36, Twig 1.28.2.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Perhaps a strange question, but what encoding is the PHP file saved in?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's in UTF-8.